# Lipo Charging Circuit- Relay vs MOSFET

Tags: mosfet, relay, battery-charging, lipo

I am currently working on an application which will use both a Lipo and an external power source (DC). The external power source will charge the lipo as well as power the system load at the same time (during Lipo charging).

Initially I have based my design on the frequently referenced microcip AN1149 design document. See below[image]

The offered solution suggests a P-channel MOSFET (Q1) and a Schottky diode (D1). My only concern is reverse current flow across the MOSFET body diode.

I understand that Lipo's have a very specific method of charging and I cant figure out if using a MIC94052 type p-channel MOSFET would interfere with the constant current/constant voltage charging process, due to reverse current through the body diode. Now, I have had a look at the datasheet (https://datasheet.lcsc.com/szlcsc/1806131131_Microchip-Tech-MIC94052YC6-TR_C87380.pdf ), and it seems like the Idss is about 1 to 5uA.

Since i have not tested this circuit with a Lipo yet, I wanted to eliminate the possibility of any damage to it. I could potentially just use  a relay instead of the MOSFET (Q1).
Other than the size increase with the relay i dont see any disadvantages. Switching would only occur once or twice a day so im not expecting a short relay life span.

My question is, is it safer to use a relay instead of the MOSFET, or is it unnecessary? Keep in mind my application will have to be running almost all the time (either from the battery or the external supply). So heat generation is a factor (MOSFET).

Comment: In AN1149:"Selecting The MOSFET" in page 5 says that the MOSFET is off if supply is from the source. MOSFET is on when supply is from the battery...unless I'm confused.

Comment: Thats correct. However when the mosfet is off, and the external supply is powering the system, there will be reverse current flow through the body diode of the mosfet. Thats why im considering a relay instead of a mosfet but im not sure if the reverse current is significant enough to make that design change.

Comment: I don't think the leakage current thru the diode is an issue. I wonder if you may end up with a higher Vbat output than the system voltage though. Two diodes may drop the supply voltage below the Vbat voltage and forward bias the mosfet body diode. I would imagine that the developers of the app. note took that into account as well as the diode leakage current. This is why we prototype :-).